# Input values are null in controller(ASP.Net MVC) using ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my Login Page I want to show error message when user enter wrong email and password without refreshing page. I am trying to send data from view to controller using ajax. But in the controller, `user.Email` and `user.Password` are null when I debug, but the Ajax call works. I want to know what is wrong there?

```html
<div class="login-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12  login-form-1">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <p>Log into your account</p>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div id="alertmessage">
                    <div class=" alert alert-danger">
                        <span>
                        Email or Password is incorrect
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
 
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <input id="Email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" value="" name="Emaillog" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                    <input id="Password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Password *" value="" name="Passwordlog" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" value="Login now" id="logbut" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
                    <a href="#" class="ForgetPwd">Forget Password?</a>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#alertmessage").hide()
    $("#logbut").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // collect the user data
        var data = {};
        data.Email = $("#Email").val();
        data.Password = $("#Password").val();

        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Account/Login",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',   
            data: {
                model: data,
                __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                returnUrl: "Account/Login"   // you can modify the returnUrl value here
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == "Fail") {
                    $("#alertmessage").show()
                }
                else  {
                    window.location.href = "/Account/MainAccount";
                }
            },
        })
    })
})
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(User user)
{
    string result = "Fail";

    User appUser = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == user.Email);

    if (appUser != null)
    {
        if (appUser.Password ==user.Password)
        {
            Session["ActiveUser"] = appUser;
            return RedirectToAction("MainAccount");   
        }
    }

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);    
}
```

[image: user.email and user.Password is null when I debugged it]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using User Model in MVC action, use parameters in

```
Login(string email, string password)
```

And in Ajax pass

```
data: 
{ 
    email : email, 
    password : password, 
    __RequestVerificationToken: token
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this.

Note: you model class property same as inside form control name

Like example

UserName
Password

In you example
you are sending a request using `ajax` but your button type is `submit` when you click on button two requests come in server one is `ajax` and the second one is `form`.

Please see this example.

```
<div class="login-container">
 <div class="row">
<div class=" col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12  login-form-1">
<h2>Login </h2>
<p>Log into your account</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post,new {id="LoginFrom" }))
{
<div id="alertmessage">
<div class=" alert alert-danger">
<span>
Email or Password is incorrect
</span>
</div>
</div>

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
<input id="Email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" value="" name="Email" />
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
<input id="Password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Password *" value="" name="Password" />
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
<input type="button" class="btnSubmit" value="Login now" id="logbut" />
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
<a href="#" class="ForgetPwd">Forget Password?</a>
</div>
}
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

> Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#alertmessage").hide()
$("#logbut").click(function (e) {   

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Login","Account")',
        type: "POST",          
        data: $("#LoginFrom").serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == "Fail") {
            $("#alertmessage").show()

            }
            else  {

                window.location.href = "/Account/MainAccount";
            }
        },
        })
    })
})
```

For more detail -> check this link https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serialize.asp

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there is error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://localhost:44348/Account/@Url.Action(%22Login%22,%22Account%22)" . I changed  url: '@Url.Action("Login","Account")' to   url: "/Account/Login".  Now it works without error but input values are null again.

Comment: Sorry for that i have miss the code in view can you please check again if possible I have update view code. in your view control name "Emaillog" and "Passwordlog" that's the resion for value not bind in model class.

Comment: The main issue is main property name not name in model so that control value not mapped.

Comment: Welcome bro :) glad to help you.